# Grails, call controller method in gsp, set default user in form

Tags: grails, view, controller, grails-orm

I'm realising authentication with the Spring Security core plugin. Now I have a class with generated CRUD views and I want to adjust them.

Part of the Domain class is a user. If the user has just "user-rights" he shouldn't be able to select a user (default user is the current user). 
If the user is an admin (authority: ROLE_ADMIN) he should be able to select all available users.

In my Controller I tried to use springSecurityService.getCurrentUser() to set the default user in my gsp. Unfortunately this results in an error:

Controller:

```
def currentUser(){
        User user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
        return user
    }
```

form.gsp:

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: daybookingInstance, field: 'user', 'error')} required">
    <label for="user">
        <g:message code="daybooking.user.label" default="User" />
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:select id="user" name="user.id" from="${usermanagement.User.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${package.controller.currentUser().id}" class="many-to-one"/>
```

In the end I dont know how to make the content of the selection variable (admin: all users, normal user: no selection) and how to set the default user (currently logged in)

EDIT: error message:

```
Caused by MissingMethodException: No signature of method: usermanagement.User.currentUser() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: currentUser()
```

EDIT:

this is my method in my controller:

```
User userInstance = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
        integer id = userInstance.id
        log.error(id)
        render(view: '_form.gsp', model : [id: id])

    }
```

I tried it with passing the whole userInstance but then I'm always getting a nullpointer exception saying I cant get id from null (in view: userInstance.id)

This is the snippet from my view (_form.gsp created by grails):

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: dailyBookingInstance, field: 'user', 'error')} required">
    <label for="user">
        <g:message code="dailyBooking.user.label" default="User" />
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:select id="user" name="user.id" from="${usermanagement.User.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${id}" class="many-to-one"/>

</div>
```

The methods are working fine because the id/userInstance are logged correctly. Somehow I got the feeling that im not suppossed to pass data to this generated stuff.

Comment: can you elaborate a little on that piece of code: ` value="${package.controller.currentUser().id}"`? I guess you try to call a controller method from a gsp, right? If so, this is not the way it works. Controllers render views and pass values to the view, not the other way around. Another thing is, that if you want to read the current user from a gsp, there is a spring security taglib for this (see the [docs](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/helperClasses.html#securityTagLib)).

Comment: Yes I wanted to call a controller method from the gsp. But you are right, thats not how it works. I added smth. like that in my controller: [user: user], this should pass the user object to the view? Problem is now when I try to access it in the view I always get the error that its null. Is there a problem with the generated CRUD views? At the moment im working in _form.gsp and have an action in my controller called currentUser().

Comment: what does you mean when write next code: usermanagement.User.list() ??

Comment: thats generated from grails/gorm and results in a dropdown menu with all users

Comment: probably `usermanagement` is just the package of the User Domain class...

Comment: No, that part is right. The only part I changed is value="${id}" to set the default user to the current logged in one. Without it I got my list with all users.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: To pass a user from a controller to a view do the following.

```
def controllerAction()
{
    //get the user instance
    User userInstance = springSecurityService.currentUser;

    //pass the user to your view
    render(view: 'theviewname', model : [userInstance: userInstance])
}
```

You can then access the userInstance in your view with ${userInstance}

### Old

You can use the Spring Security taglib.

For example:

```
<sec:ifAllGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPERVISOR">secure stuff here</sec:ifAllGranted>
```

You can see the various options available [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/helperClasses.html#securityTagLib).

Comment: Yes I saw that, but I dont think that taglib covers it all? Dont see how I can set the content of my users in <g:select> depending on the current loggend in user (admin or user). The Permissions are defined in my Controller class via @Secured Annotation. The biggest question at the moment is for me how I can pass a User from my controller to my generated CRUD Layer (_form.gsp)